# How to test that method is called after all previous async tasks are done? CompletableFuture in java

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, completable-future

I have a case where I have three methods like this:

```
public void mainMethod() {
    foo1();
    foo2();
    bar();
}
```

In second method (foo2) I am using CompletableFuture to block all async tasks which are inside:

```
Set<TaskRequest> requests = repository.findTaskRequests(TaskStatus.STATUS_LIST_FOR_DOWNLOAD);
CompletableFuture.allOf(requests.stream()
    .map(request -> runner.runTaskRequestAsync(request)
            .exceptionally(e -> {
                log.error(e.getMessage() + e);
                return null;})
            )
    .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new))
    .orTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTES, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .join();
log.info("All task request are done");
```

and task look like this:

```
@Async("executor")
public CompletableFuture<Void> runTaskRequestAsync(TaskRequest request) {
    //a lot of things are done here
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
}
```

It is working and I see that bar() method is always called after all @Async task requests are done  but how can I test it properly now?

So far I'm testing it based on log order but I don't know if that is correct way to do that.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but is the question about `.join();` ?

Comment: Can you test `foo2` in isolation? For instance, do the necessary setup, call `foo2`, then assert that all actions have been completed. If that test succeeds, you can assume that when `foo2` ends, all the asynchronous work is done. You'll probably need to mock away the actual tasks, to use something like `CountDownLatch` instead.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I want to call bar() only if all callable tasks from foo2() are done :) In normal way foo2() will call async tasks and just go to bar() (async tasks may still running and I need them to be done as first)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I achieved it through the callable future but I don't know how to test  that the bar () method is called only when all the async tasks are finished

Comment: In the code you provided there is no apparent link between `foo2()` and `bar()`. Since `foo2()` is joining on all tasks, it guarantees that all async tasks are finished, right? So as RobSpoor suggests, you could just have a test for `foo2()` to ensure that all tasks are completed when the call returns.

Comment: It’s not recognizable from the posted parts of the code what will happen on timeout.

Comment: @Holger u are right, I added exception handling a few minutes ago :)